# Writing tests to use Kafka consumer in multi-threading environment

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-kafka, thread-safety, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to create a kafka consumer in a separate thread which consumes data from kafka topic. For this, I have extended `ShutdownableThread` abstract class and provided implementation for `doWork` method. My code is like this -

```
abstract class MyConsumer(topic: String) extends ShutdownableThread(topic) {
    val props: Properties = ???
    private val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
    consumer.subscribe(List(topic).asJava)

    def process(value: String): Unit // Abstract method defining what to do with each record

    override def doWork(): Unit = {
        for (record <- consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000)).asScala)
            process(record.value())
    }
}
```

Now in my tests, I create consumer providing implementation of `process()` method which just mutates a variable and then call `start()` method of it to start the thread.

```
var mutVar = "initial_value"

val consumer = new MyConsumer("test_topic") {
    override def process(value: String): Unit = mutVar = "updated_value"
}

consumer.start()
assert(mutVar === "updated_value")
```

The Consumer does consume the message from the kafka but it does not update it before the test finishes and hence the test fails. So, I tried to put the main thread on sleep. But it throws `ConcurrentModificationException` exception with the message - `KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access`

Any idea what is wrong with my approach ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to put main thread to sleep for few seconds to allow consumer to consume message from kafka topic and store it in the mutable variable. Added - `Thread.sleep(5000)` after starting the consumer.